# Непонятный синтаксис new()

Tags: c#

Подскажите зачем оператор **new** идет в объявления класс Bank(class Bank : IBank where T : Account, **new()**)

```
interface IBank<out t="">
{
    T CreateAccount(int sum);
}

class Bank<t> : IBank<t> where T : Account, new()
{
    public T CreateAccount(int sum)
    {
        T acc = new T(); // создаем счет
        acc.DoTransfer(sum);
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это ограничение для обобщеного типа. Означает что тип `T` должен иметь публичный конструктор без параметров. [Подробности](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint).

Answer (score 4):

Это ограничение, накладываемое на параметр дженерика, требующее доступность публичного конструктора без параметров. Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint):

> The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.